# trouble making the correct query

Tags: sql, join

I have 3 tables : `tests, cases , names`.

`tests`: Contains  columns : `ID , date , name of the test`s.

`cases`: each test can have few cases , so the columns are : `ID , Test_ID, QC number`

`names`: translates QC numbers to names , so table columns are : `QC number and QC name.`

I want to create a correct query which will get me access to all fields in the correct way , but I want the results not to display duplicates.

for example  :

tests :

```
ID   date     name

1    1.1.16   test 1

2    2.2.16   test 2
```

cases:

```
ID   Test_ID    QC_NUM

1    1           QC-1234

2    1           QC-6789

3    1           QC-0003
```

names:

```
QC_NUM  QC_NAME

QC-1234  stresss

QC-6789   ping

QC-0003    pong
```

If I am looking for all tests that has `"QC-1234"` cases - I want to get only the correct line in "tests" table.

If I am looking for all tests that has "ping" test - I want to get only the correct line in "tests" table.

I hope I was clear enough..

EDIT :
here is a sample :
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f2884/4

As you can see the problem is when trying to get the data when there are no conditions - then I get duplicates.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please include the SQL CREATE statements for your tables and the SELECT statement you have so far.

Answer (score 0):

Following queries should be all right:

```
select distinct t.* 
from tests t, cases c, names n
where t.ID = c.Test_ID
and c.QC_NUM = n.QC_NUM
and c.QC_NUM = 'QC-1234'

select distinct t.* 
from tests t, cases c, names n
where t.ID = c.Test_ID
and c.QC_NUM = n.QC_NUM
and n.QC_NAME = 'ping'
```

If you want to use the join statement in your queries, which is ANSI-standard, you may also try the following:

```
select distinct t.* 
from tests t
join cases c
on t.ID = c.Test_ID
join names n
on c.QC_NUM = n.QC_NUM
where c.QC_NUM = 'QC-1234'

select distinct t.* 
from tests t
join cases c
on t.ID = c.Test_ID
join names n
on c.QC_NUM = n.QC_NUM
where c.QC_NAME = 'ping'
```

Comment: May also try? Both of this queries are exactly the same, the second one is the only proper way to write it.

Comment: @sagi The second query is ANSI standard SQL.

Comment: @tale852150 Ok, and?

Comment: @sagi I'm agreeing with you...The only difference I could see is that the second one is written in ANSI standard SQL.  :-)

Comment: Roger that @tale852150

Comment: After looking at your fiddle link, could you just not add a `distinct` to your SQL to resolve the dups?

Comment: @Mojo, as @tale852150 mentioned, you may use `distinct` in your query.